# Looking for a Sci-Fi movie about a Nazi scientist that invented a device that detected the truth and see the future

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the early seventies, I remember one night visiting some friends with my family.

They were watching on their TV a black and white sci-fi movie about a Nazi scientist that had invented an apparatus -a kind of headset and goggles- based on his experiments with Jewish High Priests (not sure but I think they were Baal Shems). The apparatus made the subjects to tell the truth (somewhat contrary to a lie detector) and also worked to see the future.

Hitler himself was interested in the invention. I remember the scientist with the Fuhrer taking his dog Blondi to walk and talking about the invention. The Fuhrer did set a demonstration with the invention as an excuse to unmask the traitor of his high command in a large room (I think it was in his Berghof home).

The last thing that I remember is Hitler tossing an ancient coin. He said that it was the same coin used by Jesus when retorting about paying tribute to Caesar and later on Alexander the Great had had it in his possession as a lucky charm.

At that moment, we had to leave. I am not sure but when we reached home, the film was ending with the traitor being electrocuted with the apparatus on while seeing the future.

Years later, I asked our friends (most of them had passed away) about the movie. Only one of them remembered that the movie started with Hitler consulting an old female seer revealing his future defeat against the Russians because of a traitor. They also remembered a boxing fight between Joe Louis and Max Schmeling and a victorious Schmeling returning to Germany in the Hindenburg and giving thanks to the scientist. And that was it. My friends said that they turned off the TV after we left that night.

The movie was in English with English subtitles during any German dialogue.